# R impute last carried forward by group and by condition

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, imputation, locf

I am attempting to impute LOCF of a numeric variable "x.val" by two groups (ID, and a cyclical categoric variable "current.group") but i want to make the groups distinct where they are separated by rows of differing groups)

```
data.frame(ID = c("1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002"), 
current.group = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c"), 
x.val = c(433, NA, NA, 362, NA, NA, 125, 158, NA, NA, NA, 111, NA, 101))
```

What i would like to achieve is an imputation only on the current group for intance, the 4th position for subject 1001 is the same grouping "a" as rows 1 and 2, but a new cycle and so i want this separated as a distinct group from rows 1&2. The result should be:

```
1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002
a, a, b, a, b, b, c, a, a, a, a, a, a, c
433, 433, NA, 362, NA, NA, 125, 158, 158, 158, 158, 111, 111, 101
```

However, if I use group_by function it will just take all instances of the "current.group" throughout the dataframe(grouped by ID). I am tending to think theres a way of creating a derived variable which indicates these distinct groups and group_by on this new variable. However, i wonder if there is a different approach in dplyr or using some other means

This is hard to explain what i mean so i hope the point comes acrross that i want a group_by but distinguishing instances separated by rows of a different group

Answer (score 0):

You can create non-cyclic groups from your cyclic grouping. After just group_by this new grouping instead.

```
df$non.cyclic.groups <- cumsum(c(0,diff(as.numeric(factor(df$current.group))))!=0)

     ID current.group x.val non.cyclic.groups
1  1001             a   433                 0
2  1001             a    NA                 0
3  1001             b    NA                 1
4  1001             a   362                 2
5  1001             b    NA                 3
6  1001             b    NA                 3
7  1001             c   125                 4
8  1002             a   158                 5
9  1002             a    NA                 5
10 1002             a    NA                 5
11 1002             a    NA                 5
12 1002             a   111                 5
13 1002             a    NA                 5
14 1002             c   101                 6
```